# How to initialize SortedMap?

Tags: java

How do I initialize the SortedMap?  Really all I need is a series of strings that maintain the order in which they're added to the series.  I'm assuming SortedMap is even the best solution.  BUT, every time I try to set `cssFiles` to an instance of `Map()` or `SortedMap()` I get nothing.

```
public class Controller {
    private SortedMap<Integer, String> cssFiles;
    private SortedMap<Integer, String> jsFiles;

    public Controller () {
        this.addCss("global.css");
        this.addJs("global.js");
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you when you said "I get nothing". Your code is also ambiguous as it's candidate for a `NullPointerException`. But that can also be just oversimplification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Really all I need is a series of strings that maintain the order in which they're added to the series

Seems you need a [List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) (either [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) or [LinkedList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) if you're not into concurrency issues).

From the javadoc:

> An ordered collection (also known as a sequence).

Answer (score 4):

Sorted collections are not used for mantaining the insertion order, they are used when you want to retrieve the items using some ordenation property related to the contents of the items.

Use ArrayList, Vector or one of the queues if you want to retrieve items in the order they were inserted.

Comment: please never use `Vector`